# How to merge 2 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> into 1, based on key values?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have 2 `ArrayList < HashMap < String, String>>`.

> list1: [{name=Alice, count=193}, {name=Bob, count=13}, {name=Charlie,
>   count=179}, ...]
>
> list2: [{name=Alice, change=1}, {name=Bob, change=15}, {name=Jimmy,
>   change=15}, ...]

All key values present in `list2` are present in `list1`, but not vice versa. For eg. since Charlie has 0 change, he is not present in `list2`. I want to merge these 2 lists based on the key values (name) to create a new `list3`.

> list3: [{name=Alice, count=193, change=1}, {name=Bob ,count=13,
>   change=15}, {name=Charlie, count=179, change=0}, ...]

Comment: Why are you using a list of key-value pairs? Shouldn't you be using a simple `Map` instead?

Comment: The data is from a json source so i just parsed it and put it into a `HashMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `list1` and `list2` do not contain duplicate `name`s you can do something like this:

```
    //list3 created.
    for(HashMap<String,String> hm2:list2){
        String nameValue=hm2.get("name");
        for(HashMap<String,String> hm1:list1){
            if(hm1.get("name").equalsIgnoreCase(nameValue)){
                HashMap<String,String> tempMap = new HashMap();
                tempMap.put("name",nameValue);
                tempMap.put("count",hm1.get("count"));
                tempMap.put("change",hm2.get("change"));
                list3.add(tempMap);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(list3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1/ create a class called `Account` which contains `name`, `count`, `change`, then the result would be a list of `Account` (if you dont want to create a new class, you can skip this step)

2/ from `list2` build a `HashMap<String (name), Integer (change)>`

3/ iterate through the `list1`, which every element, find a corresponding `change` base on the `HashMap` built in step 2, then build an `Account` (or a `HashMap` which contains all the info), add the account (or the `HashMap`) to `list3`